# Wait time on server replies Increasaed after applying joins

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlperformance

i was working on Performance improvement of one Stored procedure.
i have change it to use join in place of may sub query but it increased 
"Wait time on server replies" in "Time Statistics" which i compared in two different Query window on the same DB

**Time Statistics** (**Without Joins**  )
  Client processing time.......83
  Total execution time.........90
  Wait time on server replies   7

**Time Statistics** (**With Joins** )
Client processing time.........72
Total execution time............290
Wait time on server replies.218

please help me

1. if it will improve the performance of my procedure after removing many sub query with a join as here processing time improved?
2. why Wait time On server replies Increased?

Comment: Are the two tests comparable? Could another user have been running something when you ran the second query? How many tests have you done to get those statistics? Can you post the two queries that you are comparing?

Comment: yes they are comparable and no other user was running anything as i am working on local DB. i run the query many times got some difference in the values but that was very miner changes and wait time difference is too large in compare..
i will send some test queries as these are related to code of the client.